# Emailing my Excel Document breaks Combo Boxes

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, excel-2010

I've created an Excel Document to ease my daily work tasks which uses 4 ComboBoxes to choose values to look at in in massive tables.

This works perfectly fine on my machine, however when I email this document elsewhere, the ComboBoxes lose their properties so the VBA Coding breaks since it can't find the name of the ComboBoxes for populating upon opening the document.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheet1.ManuBox.Clear
Sheet1.ManuBox.Value = ""
Sheet1.BrandBox.Clear
Sheet1.BrandBox.Value = ""
Sheet1.SubBox.Clear
Sheet1.SubBox.Value = ""
Sheet1.FlavourBox.Clear
Sheet1.FlavourBox.Value = ""
```

The code breaks straight away here at Sheet1.ManuBox.Clear

When I go to check the properties of the ComboBox it has no properties..

Any further information required just ask!

Comment: See this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US

Comment: Is that the only workaround? Unfortunately these are work PC's I'm talking about and don't have access to the Temp file, updates etc. Was hoping it was an easy fix :(

Comment: There is no other solution that I am aware of currently.

Comment: Managed to get into the Temp files and this fixed it. Many thanks Rory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me. Will set as answered in 2 days.

See this KB: support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US

By Rory